# how to connect gremlin server with orientDB

Tags: python, orientdb, graph-databases, gremlin, gremlin-server

I am new to the gremlin-server and orientDB on Ubuntu, and I wanted to connect the orientDB to the Gremlin server. Can anyone tell me what are the requirements for the connection? I am successfully connected gremlin-server to a neo4j graph database.

Answer (score 2):

OrientDB adheres to the Apache TinkerPop standard and implements TinkerPop Stack interfaces.

In order to use the OrientDB TinkerPop Graph API implementation, you need to create an instance of the OrientGraph class. If the database already exists, the Graph API opens it.

When building multi-threaded application, use one instance of OrientGraph per thread. Bear in mind that all graph components, such as vertices and edges, are not thread safe. So, sharing them between threads may result in unpredictable results.

For more information: https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/tinkerpop3/OrientDB-TinkerPop3.html#gremlin-server

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: I wanted in python